# UrlScan and Request Filtering long url

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, url, request-filtering

Our *Windows/IIS 7.5* environment is configured with *UrlScan* and *IIS Request Filtering*. We have been facing an issue with a long url.

```
/MyWeb/TestFW/prweb/Servelt1/ZsvSk3vV8PtgJEa4_x3fiQ[[*/!MyWebApp/webwb/desktop_domainsuffix_1819019784.js!yui_13833664524!desktopwrapper_12997951049!automationscripts_1864420987!ui_jquery_1796787788!desktopwrapper_12997951049!automationscripts_1864420987!ui_jquery_1796787788!
```

Note: I modified the url, but that's the structure and it comes around 880 bytes if I put in notepad.

`UlrScan.ini` file has all default  configuration for Request Limits section:

```
MaxAllowedContentLength=30000000
MaxUrl=260
MaxQueryString=2048
```

*IIS's Request filtering* is also enabled and it has the default values:

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits
       maxAllowedContentLength="30000000"
       maxUrl="4096"
       maxQueryString="2048" 
                  />
  </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

I ran a test and the URL I provided at the top of the post failed with a 403 error. The URL is 880 bytes so, if Request Filtering takes precedence, it shouldn't fail, so I'm assuming *UrlScan* executed without considering IIS's request limits.

I asked my IIS admin to provide IIS logs couple of times and in what ever the logs shared, I see just 403. No 404 or 404.14 errors as mentioned in all other Microsoft support articles.

So is my observation correct ? with this kind of set up, which configuration takes precedence? is it UrlScan or IIS's Request Filtering ?

I'd love to hear if there an option to make Request Filtering take precedence over *UrlScan* settings, because Request Filtering is customizable until application level where as `UrlScan.ini` is customizable only until site level.

And also, as per IIS documentation, *UrlScan* features are being incorporated into IIS's request filtering, So why there is a huge difference between default values for max url? 260 bytes in `urlscan.ini` and 4096 bytes in IIS's request filtering.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, please see the answer  in answers section.

Answer (score 0):

The UrlScan  stops the request before it reaches  IIS Request Filtering module. The ideal  and recommended solution would be decommission UrlScan and use IIS Request Filtering module alone on IIS 7 and above,This module in IIS 7.5  has all the features of urlscan modules so there is no technical reason to not to decommission. But since our admins  were not comfortable with that we followed the approach below. Increase the maxUrl in urlscan module to 4096 which allows lengthy requests. 
Request Filtering module can be configured at default web site level or server level which is global and also at individual application level. So the default website level urlScan  was left at 460 characters which applies to all applications and in my application the maxUrl of Request filtering is set to 4096. In this way all the other 50 applications has the limits  set up by default years ago and my application has more length  for serving lengthy requests.

Thanks.